# Swift - Ambiguous use of subscript sort() - Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, xcode7.3

I have updated my Xcode to version 7.3, which is compatible with iOS 9.3. My sort() method, which is `let sortArr = saveDeals?.sort({ $1[2] as! String > $0[2] as! String});`, is giving me an "ambiguous use of subscript" error. Please let me know what I can do to fix this error. Thank you!

```
func sortSaveDealsArr(saveDeals: [AnyObject]?) -> [AnyObject]
{
    let sortArr = saveDeals?.sort({ $1[2] as! String > $0[2] as! String});
    return sortArr!;
}
```

Comment: What _is_ `saveDeals`? Everything depends on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `saveDeals` is typed as a `[AnyObject]?`. Thus your `$0` and `$1` are each an AnyObject, and you can't subscript an AnyObject. You need to cast each of these things to something that is itself subscriptable. I don't know what's in your array so I can't say what that would be. Is `saveDeals` an array of arrays? If so, you need to cast `saveDeals` to that.

Comment: saveDeals is actually an array of arrays. Once I changed the code to `func sortSaveDealsArr(saveDeals: [[AnyObject]]?) -> [[AnyObject]]
    {
        let sortArr = saveDeals?.sort({ $1[2] as? String > $0[2] as? String});
        return sortArr!;
    }`, the error went away and worked as intended. Thanks :)

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for reporting back.